# Can the real affine line be viewed as a "quotient" of the complex affine line, by a "complex conjugation" action?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

For a field $k$ let $L_k$ denote the affine scheme $\mathbb{A}^1_k = \mathrm{Spec}(k[x])$.

The inclusion $\Bbb R[x] \hookrightarrow \Bbb C[x]$ induces a scheme morphism $f : L_\mathbb{C}\rightarrow L_\mathbb{R}$, which should be surjective on points (by e.g. the going-up theorem).

If I'm not mistaken, the underlying continuous map of $f$ sends points as follows: a max ideal $(x-a)$ for $a\in \mathbb{C}$ is sent to the minimal polynomial $(x-a)(x-\bar{a})$ of $x-a$ over $\mathbb{R}$.
This is because the minimal polynomial generates $\mathbb{R}[x] \cap (x-a)$. Note both $a,\bar{a}$ are sent to the same point.
Furthermore, this clearly sends non-conjugate $a,b\in\mathbb{C}$ to different points (different minimal polynomials).

---

I was wondering if it makes sense to say there should be a group scheme $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ acting on the scheme $L_\mathbb{C}$ by "complex conjugation", and the quotient gives the scheme $L_\mathbb{R}$? How would this be formalized in detail?

Comment: Yes, that’s right. It’s a little easier to see the dual statement in terms of commutative rings. A more general statement is true for any finite Galois extension. I can write an answer with more details later.